# Cannot Upload file to Alfresco with Curl

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a php script that uploads files to Alfresco using curl, it works fine with local setup of Alfresco on my system. But, fails when the same is used to upload to production copy.

Below, is the curl response upon failure while uploading file,

```
{
  "status" :
{
  "code" : 500,
  "name" : "Internal Error",
  "description" : "An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
},

"message" : "00031437 Unexpected error occurred during upload of new content.",
"exception" : "org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 00031437 Unexpected error occurred during upload of new content.",

"callstack" :
[
   ""      ,"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class {}application\/pdf has not been defined in the data dictionary"
  ,"org.alfresco.repo.policy.ClassPolicyDelegate.get(ClassPolicyDelegate.java:98)"
  ,"org.alfresco.repo.policy.ClassPolicyDelegate.get(ClassPolicyDelegate.java:83)"
  ,"org.alfresco.repo.node.AbstractNodeServiceImpl.invokeBeforeCreateNode(AbstractNodeServiceImpl.java:283)"
  ,"org.alfresco.repo.node.db.DbNodeServiceImpl.createNode(DbNodeServiceImpl.java:363)"
  ,"sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1147.invoke(Unknown Source)"
  ,"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
  ,"java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)"
  ,"org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)"
  ,"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)"
  ,"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)"
  ,"org.alfresco.repo.tenant.MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.invoke(MultiTNodeServiceInterceptor.java:104)"
  ,"org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)"
  ,"org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)"
  ,"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.createNode(Unknown Source)"
  ,"sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1147.invoke(Unknown Source)"
  ,"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
  ,"java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)"
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Very hard to tell based on the info given. Seems the system tries to create a node using the mime type as the local qname. I would guess the data you send does not quite match watch Alfresco expects. What data/parameters) are you sending to which address (URL) ?

Comment: Below is the code that I use, works fine on local copy of Alfresco. But, throws error on production server.

   `$url ='http://admin:passwd@WEBURL:8000/alfresco/service/api/upload';
    $filename = 'john.jpeg';
    $mimetype=  mime_content_type($filename);

    $postfields = array(
      'filedata' => '@' . $filename,
      'filename' => $filename,
      'siteid' => 'mysite',
      'containerid' =>'documentLibrary',
      'uploaddirectory' =>'test',
      'contenttype' => $mimetype
    );`

Answer (score 2):

The value of `contenttype` must be a valid type qname. Have a look at the documentation at `http://WEBURL:8000/alfresco/service/index/uri/api/upload`. If in doubt, try `cm:content` or it's full representation.

Comment: Hard to tell why, but it pretty much looks like $mimetype has a value of "application/pdf" and using this as contenttype is wrong. Double check what you pass in. If this value really works on your system, maybe you (accidently) managed to create a content type with local name "application/pdf" and no namespace.

Comment: Fixed. Just removed the content type from post fields.